# Given span of 8 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ If your REF has five leading ones, do those vectors become a basis of your span

Tags: linear-algebra

Given span of 8 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$, if your REF has five leading ones, do those vectors become a basis of your span?

It's a $5 \times 8$ matrix in row reduced form which has no zero rows, and we have $5$ leading ones.

Comment: So, you took your eight vectors, lined them up as the columns of a $5\times 8$ matrix, and row reduced.  Yes, the columns which contain a leading $1$ after row reduction correspond to which of the original vectors can be used as a basis for the span of them... Of course... in your specific case you have eight vectors who span a five dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^5$... which is the entirety of $\Bbb R^5$ so you could have chosen any basis for $\Bbb R^5$, whichever makes you most comfortable, including the traditional elementary basis.

Comment: "*do those vectors become a basis of your span*" I hope I am not reading you suggest that *all eight* of the vectors become your basis...

Answer (score 0):

Any set of 5 linearly independent vectors are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$, and any basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ is set of five linearly independent vectors. so if you have 5 vectors chosen from 8 ones and you know that they're independent (which means you cannot change any of them to zero by reducing the matrix), they're a basis.